# How can I get the type name of DOM using goquery?

Tags: dom, go, goquery

I want to get the type name of DOM like 'a', img', 'tr', 'td', 'center' using goquery.
How can I get?

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
)

func main() {
    doc, _ := goquery.NewDocument("https://news.ycombinator.com/")
    doc.Find("html body").Each(func(_ int, s *goquery.Selection) {
        // for debug.
        println(s.Size()) // return 1

        // I expect '<center>' on this URL, but I can't get it's name.
        // println(s.First().xxx) // ?
    })
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`*Selection.First`](https://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection.First) gives you another [`*Selection`](https://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection) which contains a slice of [`*html.Node`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html#Node) which has a `Data` field which contains:

> tag name for element nodes, content for text

So something like that:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
    "golang.org/x/net/html"
)

func main() {
    doc, _ := goquery.NewDocument("https://news.ycombinator.com/")
    doc.Find("html body").Each(func(_ int, s *goquery.Selection) {
        // for debug.
        println(s.Size()) // return 1

        if len(s.Nodes) > 0 && s.Nodes[0].Type == html.ElementNode {
            println(s.Nodes[0].Data)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see.
I understood that `Data` string is tag name.
Thank you for your advice.
Your code is clear and safety. It's helpfull for me. Thank you.